# How to create dataframe with increasing timestamp column?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I can inject `timestamp` in a dataframe column. But I wanted the `timestamp` column to be unique value (or increasing in nature, even by millisecond). What I currently have -

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
df = spark.createDataFrame(["10","11","13"], "string").toDF("age")
df = df.withColumn("ts", lit(datetime.now()))
display(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a timestamp for each row, that is unique over the DataFrame depending on when Spark processes that row, because the data is distributed, so you’ll never have control over when that row was processed. That being said:

1. If you want the current timestamp to be added as a column, you’ll get  better mileage if you use `pyspark.sql.functions.current_timestamp`.
2. If you want a column that provides increasing indices, use [`pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id).